# What's the point of the X500Principal(String, Map) constructor?

Tags: java

I was test driving the `X500Principal` class like so:

```
Map<String, String> attr = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
attr.put("CN", "Duke");
attr.put("O", "JavaSoft");
X500Principal p1 = new X500Principal("", attr);
X500Principal p2 = new X500Principal("CN=Duke,O=JavaSoft");
```

From the Javadocs, one should get the impression that `p1` and `p2` should compare equal, but unfortunately they don't. Using the various `getName` methods on `p1` I could figure that I always get an empty string.

So I wonder what's the point of passing in a map into the constructor (or the `getName(String, Map)` method)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword map should map attribute names to OID strings. The idea is that you can define your own attribute names that are not part of the standard list (CN, O, OU, etc.).

So the usage would be something like:

```
Map<String, String> attr = new HashMap<String, String>();
attr.put("FOO", "1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9");
X500Principal p = new X500Principal("CN=bar,FOO=baz", attr);
```